# Find out Git remote repo

Tags: git

How can i find remote physical path of project from clone path.
my path for cloning is http://username@servername:port/scm/abc/abc.git

any help appriciated.

Comment: It might be in `/home/username/port/scm/abc/abc.git` but maybe not, depends on what git-service you use and how it's configured.

Comment: You can ask the administrator or try to find the path scm/abc/abc.git in the server.

Comment: there is no such path scm/abc/abc.git

Comment: I think you need to find where in the site's directory does the server redirect when you hit `servername:port` and then start navigating from there to abc.git.